Nontrivial channel that is identity only on separable states?
Is there a channel that acts like the identity channel on any separable state but acts non-trivially on at least one entangled state? If not, is there a proof that such a channel cannot exist?

Such a channel cannot exist.
Channels are linear maps, and you can express any state (in fact, any matrix) as a linear combination (not convex combination!) of separable states.
By linearity, it follows that the channel must be equal to the identity channel.

(To see that any state $\rho$ can be written as a linear combination of separable states, you can e.g. use that $\sigma:=\lambda\rho + (1-\lambda)I/D$ is separable for $\lambda$ small enough, and write the state as a linear combination of $\sigma$ and the maximally mixed state $I/D$.)
